# How to do page up / down with as400 emulator tn5250 on notepad computer

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have problem with tn5250 (AS400 emulator) with my desktop page up and page down works well. But with my laptop I does not work.
What I did

- unlock the num lock and try to press 9 or 3 but nothing happend.

This is more than anoying because this type is mandatory very often.

Comment: Like Mide said in his answer, this is usually related to the emulator settings.  Unfortunately in this case, tn5250 is a pretty simplistic emulator and I don't know of any way to change the key mappings.  You will probably have to switch to a different emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this, please check if your scroll lock is on, if yes, please turn it off and then try.

Else, as mentioned in the above answer, it may be a keyboard mapping error, which can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Most often this is a mismapped keyboard in the emulator. I use the emulator that comes with iSeries Access for Windows. Choose Edit, Preferences, Keyboard, Customize.  In that window you can edit your keyboard mapping. I usually make sure the number pad, Ctrl-C, and Ctrl-V work.  On a laptop, you may have to set what command gets sent in combination with a shift or control key. I have never had that problem with page up and page down because I have only used keyboards where that is a dedicated key.